# "Practicable" versus "Feasible"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

For me, and based on dictionaries, both of the words "practicable" and "feasible" mean the same thing. I wonder if I'm mistaken, provide me with some examples where one of them is preferred over the other one so that I could recognize their correct equivalence in my own language or at least I could equalize them with a more fitting meaning.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't the same.
"Feasible" means "you are able to do it". "Practicable" means "it makes sense to do it".

For example, "we'll build a bridge across the Atlantic as soon as it's feasible" would mean, as soon as we figure out the challenges in building the bridge, we're building it regardless of cost or potential use.

On the other hand, "we'll build a bridge across the Atlantic as soon as it's practicable" means we might be able to build that bridge now, but it costs too much and/or taking a plane/boat is still easier/faster/cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Practicable is "able to be done or put into practice successfully."

Feasible is "possible to do easily or conveniently."

They are listed as synonyms of each other.

So in an official sense they are interchangeable. From a native speaker I would think of practicable being applied to an action that is repeatable stemming from the word practice. Example- "Kicking a football through the upright is a practicable task". When utilizing the word feasible, my mind goes much towards a larger task, typically a one time activity that requires something to be achieved to make it happens. An example: "Raising ten thousand dollars makes this bridge feasible". Another example: "The timeline for this project is feasible."